# monaca Onsen UIでangular.moduleをするとエラーが起こる

Tags: onsen-ui, angularjs

monacaでOnsen UI Tabberを使用しています。
JsonでHTMLタグ入りの変数を$scopeし、ng-bind-htmlで表示しようとしていますが
ngSanitizeを読み込むために

```
var app=angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);//(1)
```

をすると
**Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined**
と出てしまい何も表示されなくなります。
(1)を書かなければこのエラーは出なくなりますが、HTMLタグがエスケープされてしまうので書かないわけには行きません。
何がいけないのでしょうか？
ちなみにmonacaテンプレのOnsen UI Tabberを使わず、最小限のテンプレートにangular.js、angular-sanitize.jsを手作業で追加すれば上記のようなことは起こらず正常に動作します。

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="js/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
        <script>
            ons.bootstrap();
            var app=angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
            app.controller('MainController',function($scope){
                  datas= [
                     {"id":"1", "str":"<b>おはようございます</b>"},
                     {"id":"2","str":"<strong>こんにちは</strong>"},
                     {"id":"3","str":"<b>さようなら</b>"},
                     {"id":"4","str":"<strong>おやすみなさい</strong>"}];
                $scope.msg =datas;
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <ons-tabbar var="tabbar">
            <ons-tabbar-item
                icon="home"
                label="Home"
                page="navigator.html"
                active="true"></ons-tabbar-item>
            <ons-tabbar-item
                icon="comment"
                label="Comments"
                page="page2.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
            <ons-tabbar-item
                icon="gear"
                label="Settings"
                page="page3.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
        </ons-tabbar>

    </body>
    </html>
```

page1.html

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">一番基本的なAngularJSアプリ</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item ng-repeat="data in msg">
            {{data.id}}：<span ng-bind-html="data.str"></span>
        </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
  </div>
</ons-page>
```

助言くだされば助かります。
何卒よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

こんな感じの書き方もできるみたいです。

プロジェクトの`README.md`より

```
<script>
    var app=angular.module('app', ['onsen', 'ngSanitize']);
    app.controller('MainController',function($scope){
          datas= [
             {"id":"1", "str":"<b>おはようございます</b>"},
             {"id":"2","str":"<strong>こんにちは</strong>"},
             {"id":"3","str":"<b>さようなら</b>"},
             {"id":"4","str":"<strong>おやすみなさい</strong>"}];
        $scope.msg =datas;
    });
</script>
```

[Onsen UI Guide](http://ja.onsen.io/guide/overview.html)の「AngularJSからOnsen UIを使う」より

```
<script>
    var app=ons.bootstrap('app', ['onsen', 'ngSanitize']);
    app.controller('MainController',function($scope){
          datas= [
             {"id":"1", "str":"<b>おはようございます</b>"},
             {"id":"2","str":"<strong>こんにちは</strong>"},
             {"id":"3","str":"<b>さようなら</b>"},
             {"id":"4","str":"<strong>おやすみなさい</strong>"}];
        $scope.msg =datas;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
ons.bootstrap();を消して
var app=ons.bootstrap('app', ['onsen', 'ngSanitize']);
としたらうまくいきました。
勉強不足でお恥ずかしいです。
本当に助かりました。ありがとうございました！！